# CSS Template and visual studio MVC project

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, html

So I've downloaded some CSS templates to help make my website look nicer. I have an MVC 3 project for my final year of study, and I don't want it to look like the same generic MVC layout that everyone is using. Is it possible to easily integrate a template or are there special MVC templates out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to easily integrate a template ?

**Yes, surely.** Just change the code in views with respective HTML. You can see [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0O0gi2m_p_o) video for more details.